# Mutex errors when using OpenCV in CLION. (Windows, C++)

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, clion

CMakelist.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(Facial_Recognition main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( Facial_Recognition ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:/Users/user/OneDrive - De Montfort University/Work/headshot.jpg");
    namedWindow("Display image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
```

The errors I get when trying to use the above code:

> [ 50%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/Facial_Recognition.dir/main.cpp.obj In file included from
> C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core.hpp:3307:0,
> from C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
> from C:\Users\user\Desktop\Facial Recognition\main.cpp:2:
> C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:718:14: error:
> 'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type  typedef
> std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:719:25: error:
> 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'  typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex>
> AutoLock;
> ^~ C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:719:34: error:
> template argument 1 is invalid  typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex>
> AutoLock;
> ^ In file included from C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_index.h:44:0,
> from C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h:38,
> from C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:44,
> from C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann.hpp:48,
> from C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:65,
> from C:\Users\user\Desktop\Facial Recognition\main.cpp:2: C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/heap.h:
> In static member function 'static cv::Ptrcvflann::Heap<T >
> cvflann::Heap::getPooledInstance(const HashableT&, int, int)':
> C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/heap.h:191:20: error: 'Mutex' in
> namespace 'cv' does not name a type
> static cv::Mutex mutex;
> ^~~~~ C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/flann/heap.h:192:33: error: 'mutex'
> was not declared in this scope
> const cv::AutoLock lock(mutex);
> ^~~~~ mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Facial_Recognition.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
> mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Facial_Recognition.dir/all] Error
> 2 mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Facial_Recognition.dir/rule]
> Error 2 mingw32-make.exe: *** [Facial_Recognition] Error 2
> CMakeFiles\Facial_Recognition.dir\build.make:71: recipe for target
> 'CMakeFiles/Facial_Recognition.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
> CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target
> 'CMakeFiles/Facial_Recognition.dir/all' failed
> CMakeFiles\Makefile2:88: recipe for target
> 'CMakeFiles/Facial_Recognition.dir/rule' failed Makefile:123: recipe
> for target 'Facial_Recognition' failed

Essentially what I am asking is how I fix this, where do I fix this?

I am using MINGW32, should I bring my C++ standard down or do I need to use a newer compiler? (I am quite inexperienced)

Comment: CMakeLists.txt should use `project` and `cmake_minimum_required` commands.  Next, requiring C++23 for Mingw under Windows is pointless - this compiler is rather old. Next, your program compiles perfectly well on my machine. Conclusion: you have faulty installation of MinGW, OpenCV or whatever. Besides, what's your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.